# Who are the so called "seven" scholars of Medina?

Tags: history, islamic-scholar

It is often mentioned that [Sa'id ibn al-Mussayib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Said_ibn_al-Musayyib) سعید بن المسیب was one of the 7 scholars or fuqahaa' of Medina.
My guess is that this refers to scholars of the age of the followers (at-Tabi'yn التابعين), but this era might similarlyto that of the sahabah be divided into sighar and kibar as-Sahabah (Sahabah who were very young when the prophet() died or when they met the prophet() I'm not 100% clear about the correct use of this term).

- Who are the others?
- Where they really seven and why where they called so?
- Did all of them live at the same time period?

This might look as a multi question post, but I guess we can only know whether these questions are really that much different after receiving an answer or input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seven scholars ( فقهاء السبعة ) is the title given to a group of prominent jurists among the Tabieen who lived in the same place and time period, i.e. in Medinah contemporary to the governorship of Umar ibn Abdul Aziz. They include:

1. Sa'eed ibn al-Musayyab ( سعيد بن المسيب )
2. Urwa ibn al-Zubayr ibn Al-Awam ( عروة بن الزبير )
3. Qasim ibn Muhammad ibn Abu Bakr ( قاسم بن محمد بن أبي بكر )
4. Ubaydullah ibn 'Abdullah ibn Utba ibn Mas'ud ( عبيد الله بن عتبة بن مسعود )
5. Kharija ibn Zayd ibn Thabit ( خارجة بن زيد بن ثابت )
6. Sulayman ibn Yasar ( سليمان بن يسار )
7. There are different views on it:

   - Abu Bakr ibn Abdur Rahman ibn al-Harith ( أبو بكر بن عبد الرحمن بن الحارث )
   - Salim ibn Abdullah ibn Umar ( سالم بن عبد الله بن عمر )
   - Abu Salama ibn Abdur Rahman ibn Awf ( أبو سلمة بن عبد الرحمن بن عوف )

Ref: https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/225018/

Comment: Was it really during the caliphate of 'Umar ibn 'Abd'al'Aziz or earlier during his administration of Medina?